# Should I sync animations from the server to the client or let the client play its own animations?

Tags: networking, client-server, synchronization

For example, if the user presses the "Fire" button which leads to the player character doing some kind of animation, should the client evaluate itself if it can play the animation or wait for a response from the server telling it that it's ok to play the animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going with the authoritative server model (to limit player cheating), you want to simulate everything immediately on the client. Otherwise, there will be latency, so the player could press fire, and 200ms later see the animation, which would be a poor experience.

When the server sends back updates, the client must rewind to the state last processed by the server, then replay any local inputs not yet processed by the server to appear responsive.

See this tutorial series: http://www.gabrielgambetta.com/fpm1.html

Comment: Yes I was thinking that but how would you avoid disagreements from the server? Say the Client casts a spell so the cast spell animation is played but the server says the client can't cast the spell because he actually has no mana.

Comment: In disagreements, the server always wins. It's up to you on what to display on the client. For instance, you can start playing the animation, then stop if the server denies the cast. Immediately display the aesthetic feedback, but don't deal any damage until the server approves it. One AAA example is in Halo 3, a grenade throw would start the throwing animation, but the grenade wouldn't actually appear until the server verified it.